# how to use props inside props in styled component in react js

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I need to change the background color in condition wise ex below:

```
background-color: ${({bg})=>bg ? `${({theme})=>theme.color}`:#ffffff;
```

But its not working, can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Describe the logic you want to apply.

Comment: show us all the components and how u wanna use it. we need global photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this way :

```
background-color: ${({ theme, bg })=> bg ? theme.color : #ffffff ;
```

you should use string instead of boolean like this :

```
<div bg='yes'>

background-color: ${({ theme, bg })=> bg === 'yes' ? theme.color : #ffffff
```

Comment: The `#ffffff` should be a string.